# Cannot access the DOM from <iframe> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load HTML markup from a separate file placed in the same directory. To achieve that, I am following this article: [HTML Includes That Work Today](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/html-includes/).

I have two files with the following contents:
`page2.html`:

```html
<html>
    <style>
        div {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #0902;
            border: 2px solid green;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="x">Contents</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`test.html`:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="page2.html" style="display: none;" onload="alert('onload event called'); this.before(this.contentDocument.body.children[0]); this.remove();"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the contents of `page2.html` to get appended to the current document. But, I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload (test.html:10)
```

What mistake have I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross-origin issue.

A frame will not allow you access to the DOM of a page on a different origin.

Chrome reports the error you see when you open the HTML document from a local file.

Local files are always treated as different origins (imagine if someone emailed you an HTML document, you double clicked it, your email client saved it to a local file and opened in your browser and then started reading files from your hard disk and sending them to the sender of the email).

You need to access these documents over HTTP.

Comment: "Local files are always treated as different origins" not always no, this is a per browser rule that has changed over time, and even depends on which API is making the call... For instance in Firefox OP would have been able to access that document since it's in the same directory. However if they did try to fetch it through AJAX it would have failed there too. And regarding your example this would imply that the "bad script" knows which file name to request... Not that big of a deal.

Comment: @Kaiido — Firefox [fixed that security hole in version 68](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730), and you don't need to known the filename, you just need to guess it (and there are plenty of files which common software stores in standard locations that could be guessed).

Comment: The link you pasted is about `fetch`(i.e "AJAX"). In Firefox 88 iframes can still access resource in the same directory, you can still load an image or video in a same-origin way and thus read their content etc.

Comment: @Kaiido — I just tested it. Firefox was unable to read the contents of the file in the iframe with JavaScript. (And *displaying* images and video across origin has never been forbidden, just reading the data into JavaScript).

Comment: You probably did it wrong.  It works just fine opening an html file from the same directory through an iframe and then accessing the loaded document from the main page in Firefox. And I explicitly said  "you can still load an image or video in a same-origin way and thus **read** their content" That's the whole point:  In Firefox you can **read** the data from medias loaded from the file system in same directory. E.g you can read the pixels of images or videos through a canvas, you can read the data of an audio through the Web Audio API etc.